# Reasons for the incapacity of the "people in red", when trying to stop Alice

Tags: plot-explanation, dont-worry-darling

I presume that the "people in red" were -- just like the simulated kids -- part of the simulation itself. The reason for that is the fact that they always appear (and then disappear), in mass, when they're needed.

Considering that presumption, how was it possible that the "people in red" -- presumably the "agent Smiths" of the simulated world presented in the film -- were actually racing to capture Alice, as absolute equals, without any "extra" abilities? (and eventually lost that race)

I mean -- that's a simulation, anything's possible; especially when there's such a dramatic event unfolding, where Alice actually must not reach the "exit gate", under any circumstances.
I presume, they could just appear anywhere -- without having to race to that location

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Henchman can't shoot [or run or catch or drive or…]

Comment: It seemed like they were everywhere, so surely they could intercept her?